# GCP Cloud Run deploy: "Failed to move user code into storage". What does this mean?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, devops, google-cloud-run

Deploying a new service into Google Cloud Run fails with the message:

> Failed to move user code into storage, please verify the pod
>   configuration and try it again.

[image]

What does this mean, and how can one go about debugging it?

Comment: What did you perform as operation? Do you deployed a service? If so, where is hosted the container image? Do you deploy on managed or gke platform?

Comment: This is a bug we're tracking internally at Google to fix. Ideally you should not be seeing this error. I recommend redeploying to unblock yourself.

Comment: I'm told this error might be occurring from something like invalid entrypoint (like file not found). Make sure you're able to run this container locally. https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/testing/local (Ideally we will be surfacing a better error message for this.) Let me know how it goes here.

Comment: Thank you @AhmetB-Google, that's exactly right! This was caused by a missing entrypoint, and bad local testing on my part. It would be great to see a more descriptive error from GCR when something like this happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for the sake of giving this question an answer. All the credit should go to AhmetB and his insight about this being a Known issue to Google, In which a missing or invalid entrypoint will cause this issue to surface.

I have found a Public Issue Tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/154404997), in which this issue has also been forwarded to Google by that channel. Google will be delivering further information on that PIT.